# Installing ldap extension Docker

Tags: php, docker, ldap

Hey all I am trying to instal ldap extension on a Docker php:5.6-fm images I need ldap for my project.

I have tired to install the extension through Dockerfile like so:

```
RUN apt-get install php5-ldap -y
```

get this error:

```
The LDAP PHP extension is not enabled.
```

I have also found some 'suggestion' [online](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/75) like so:

```
RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install libldap2-dev -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ && \
    docker-php-ext-install ldap
```

get this error:

```
An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
```

am I doing something wrong...? How do I install ldap in a docker image so that I can use it in my project...?

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: ok why  
superuser.com ?

Comment: because there is no programming in this question

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I did... and it's working. I had other modules configured, but I don't think they interfere with anything.

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get update -y \
 && apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev vim

# Configure MongoDB.
RUN pecl install mongodb \
 && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

# Configure MySQL.
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

# Configure LDAP.
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install libldap2-dev -y \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
 && docker-php-ext-install ldap

RUN a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart

# Python 2.7 and modules
RUN apt install python2.7 python-pip -y \
 && python2.7 -m pip install pymysql pymongo redis

# We must reconfigure here the CMD directive.
CMD apache2-foreground
```